# QPrintPreviewWidget freezes the application when the horizontal scrollbar is shown

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qscrollarea, qprinter

I am having a bug with QPrintPreviewWidget (PySide2 5.15.2.1, Windows 11). From the moment I made this post, I didn't found anything related online.

When I force the horizontal scrollbar to appear inside the inherited scroll area (by resizing the window), the application becomes unresponsive, freezing instantly until you luckly resize the widget and force the scrollbar to disappear.

Here's a example to force trigger the bug:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtGui import QTextDocument
from PySide2.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintPreviewWidget

app = QApplication()

doc = QTextDocument()
doc.setPlainText('\n' * 200)

printer = QPrinter()
view = QPrintPreviewWidget(printer)
view.paintRequested.connect(doc.print_)

window = QWidget()
layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(view)
layout.addWidget(QLabel('Just to trigger the horizontal scrollbar'))
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

I had to create a document with more than 1 page, to force the vertical scrollbar to appear. When resized horizontally, at some point the horizontal scrollbar will become visible and lag the application.

The only way I found so far to "fix" the error is to set a minimum width to the QPrintPreviewWidget, using QPrintPreviewWidget.setMinimumWidth. This prevents the widget from reaching a small width, dodging (but not fixing) the issue.

Do anyone know a way to solve this issue?

Comment: See [QTBUG-20677](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-20677).

Comment: @ekhumoro good to know its already been reported, but the post is old... Yeah I don't think it'll be fixed soon. Better to stick with dodging the issue then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPrintPreviewWidget implements an internal QGraphicsView, meaning that this issue is closely related to the [`fitInView()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) warning:

> Note though, that calling fitInView() from inside resizeEvent() can lead to unwanted resize recursion, if the new transformation toggles the automatic state of the scrollbars.

The problem is caused by the fact that `fitInView()` may cause **one** scroll bar to appear, which reduces the available area for the viewport, possibly forcing another resize event for it and, thus, another `fitInView()` call.
That call will then decrease the visible scene rect ratio so that the first scroll bar may not be required anymore, causing another `fitInView()` call; therefore, we get recursion.

Long story short, there is no real fix for this.

Similar issues may be worked around for QGraphicsViews on which we have direct control (for example, by delaying `fitInView()` calls and using smart, accurate recursion checks), but that's not feasible for an object internally created by Qt like in this case.

The only viable and always safe solution is to make the scroll bar always visible; it may be a bit ugly, but it works:

```py
    graphicsView = view.findChild(QGraphicsView)
    graphicsView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```

If you don't like to see a non functioning scroll bar, then the only alternative is to create a "virtual" scroll bar that will eventually be *visible* only when necessary, while still occupying its required space. This means that you will always get an empty gap at the bottom of the view.

Here is a possible implementation:

```py
class PrintPreviewFix(QPrintPreviewWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        view = self.findChild(QGraphicsView)
        view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.realScrollBar = view.horizontalScrollBar()

        self.virtualScrollBar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        pol = self.virtualScrollBar.sizePolicy()
        pol.setRetainSizeWhenHidden(True)
        self.virtualScrollBar.setSizePolicy(pol)
        layout = self.layout()
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(self.virtualScrollBar)

        self.realScrollBar.rangeChanged.connect(self.updateScrollBar)
        self.realScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(self.updateScrollBar)
        self.virtualScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(self.realScrollBar.setValue)

    def updateScrollBar(self):
        minimum = self.realScrollBar.minimum()
        maximum = self.realScrollBar.maximum()
        with QSignalBlocker(self.virtualScrollBar):
            self.virtualScrollBar.setRange(minimum, maximum)
            self.virtualScrollBar.setValue(self.realScrollBar.value())
        self.virtualScrollBar.setVisible(minimum != maximum)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateScrollBar()
```

Note that the above could also be theoretically achieved just by using the existing scroll bar and toggling `setUpdatesEnabled()` on it depending on the scroll bar range (whether minimum and maximum are the same), but it's possible that this approach would eventually result in some graphics artifacts caused by buffering.

Also note that QStyles implement scroll areas in different ways; most importantly:

- the style may show the "viewport frame" *within* the area eventually occupied by scroll bars, while others show the scroll bars *inside* it;
- the style may use *transient* scroll bars, which are not considered for the viewport size and only become visible and "overlaid" inside it when the mouse cursor hovers them or temporarily when a scrolling action is triggered;

A proper implementation of the above should always consider these aspects: for instance, if transient scroll bars are used, this means that the issue will not exist at all in the first place, because visibility changes of the scroll bars won't alter the available area of the viewport.

Comment: I just don't understand when you say: _QPrintPreviewWidget implements an internal QGraphicsView_. Where in the docs does it says that? I only found it, in the first section, telling about inheritances, not implementations.

Comment: @CarlHR There's no mention about it in the docs, they probably thought it was not important to make developers aware of it. I don't know why they decided to use a QWidget container for it instead of directly inheriting from QGraphicsView, maybe they chose to use a further encapsulation level in order to better separate the widget functionality from the actual view/scene implementation, while also keeping the public API simpler.

Comment: @musicamante I tried both your solutions, and they both have exactly the same buggy behaviour as the original. What platform and Qt versions did you test on? I tested on arch-linux with a patched qt-5.15.2 and also a vanilla qt-5.15.2 pip-installed in a venv. The way I trigger the bug is to resize the window vertically until all four pages are shown. I found the only truly "safe" option is have *both* scroll-bars always on. (PS: note also that the OP is using PySide2, which doesn't have context-manager support for QSignalBlocker).

Comment: I confess that when I accepted the answer, I was simply satisfied in knowing when the bug would happen (ie when the recursion happens), and I didn't need to test the code at that moment (even though in the post I did wrote I would like to know a way to fix it). What @ekhumoro says is correct, I did tested the code now, out of curiosity, and the example doesn't fix anything. I substituted QSignalBlocker with a try-except block, calling both disconnect and connect on the virtualScrollBar.valueChanged signal (though I don't know if QSignalBlocker does anything else besides supressing signals).

Comment: @CarlHR QSignalBlocker is an alternative to QObject.blockSignals. The equivalent code would be `blocked = self.virtualScrollBar.blockSignals(True) ... self.virtualScrollBar.blockSignals(blocked)` (or just use `False` instead of the `blocked` variable). But in any case, that will make no difference to how the code behaves. I may have a look at the Qt source code at some point to see if I can find an alternative work-around. However, it seems to be a long-standing bug, so I'm not very hopeful.

Comment: @ekhumoro I only tried with an old 5.7 I use for some tests, but I admit that I didn't try it on 5.15 because as far as I could see there were no changes in that widget (it's fundamentally identical since the latest Qt4). I didn't test it with the four page case, though, which indeed could cause issues due to the scene changes even when only one scroll bar is visible. I'll check it later, thanks for the report!

Comment: @CarlHR Sorry, I didn't test it thoroughly, and after ekhumoro's comment I realize where the issue may pop up again even when making the horizontal scroll bar always hidden. In the meantime, the suggestion about always showing *both* scroll bars is always valid, I am not sure there's a way to really fix that, if not by extending my second suggestion to *both* the "virtual scroll bars".